# Even Load Distribution of JMS Queue listeners not happening

Tags: spring-boot, jms, cxf, ibm-mq, camel-cxf

I have 2 instances of my application (2 different machines) configured to listen on a single IBM MQ queue, each of them configured with 4 concurrent consumers in the cxf bean.

```
<bean id="TestConfig0" class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration" 
    p:sessionTransacted="false" p:connectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory0" p:concurrentConsumers="4"
    p:targetDestination="TestQueue" p:deliveryMode="1"/>
```

When I run my application to read the data from the above queue. I see that 70% of the messages are picked up by server1 and only 30% by server2.

All the configurations are equal among both the app instances with respect to the JMS configuration.

Its bit strange to observe this pattern. 
How do i ensure that both my app instance pick the messages from the Queues evenly ??

Answer (score 0):

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744556/how-does-ibm-mq-qm-distribute-messages-over-multiple-consumers/50745789#50745789) to a similar question:

> MQ's default behaviour is to give messages to the MOST RECENT getter.